# MulterError: Unexpected field at wrappedFileFilter

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file to S3 on Amazon by creating an API,,, however, I am having issues while uploading the file.
The API has an issue when I select the file using postman I get the error below
I don't get the source of the issue

```
MulterError: Unexpected field
    at wrappedFileFilter (E:\MyProjects\reapmgtapi\node_modules\multer\index.js:40:19)
    at Busboy.<anonymous> (E:\MyProjects\reapmgtapi\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:114:7)
    at Busboy.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Busboy.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
    at Busboy.emit (E:\MyProjects\reapmgtapi\node_modules\busboy\lib\main.js:38:33)
    at PartStream.<anonymous> (E:\MyProjects\reapmgtapi\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:213:13)
    at PartStream.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at PartStream.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
    at HeaderParser.<anonymous> (E:\MyProjects\reapmgtapi\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:51:16)
    at HeaderParser.emit (events.js:198:13)
```

**Here are my project files** 
 
**multer.config.js**

```js
const multer = require('multer');

var storage = multer.memoryStorage()
var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

module.exports = upload;
```

**controller.js**

```js
const s3 = require('../config/s3.config');
const env = require('../config/s3.env');

exports.doUpload = (req, res) => {
    const params = {
        Bucket: env.Bucket,
        Key: req.file.originalname,
        Body: req.file.buffer
    }

    s3.upload(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send("Error is as follows -> " + err);
        }
        res.send("File uploaded successfully! -> keyname = " + req.file.originalname);
    });
}
```

**s3.router.js**

```js
let express = require('express');
let router = express.Router();

let upload = require('../config/multer.config');

const awsWorker = require('../controllers/controller');

router.post('/api/files/upload', upload.single("file"), awsWorker.doUpload);
module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code is fine,,, I just had to create a request with a file with **"file"** as the key and the file input as the parameter... I was trying to input the originalname and buffer parameters which should be extracted from the file